# Multi-line i18n-tasks-use statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, rubocop, i18n-gem

We have a repo that gets its I18n keys from incoming requests. So, I've been using `i18n-tasks-use`to explicitly declare all the keys we intend to use to satisfy our linter.

E.g.:

`i18n-tasks-use # i18n-tasks-use t('notification.notification_name.alt_1')`

However, some of the `i18n-tasks-use` statements are running over the rubocop line length limit. I've tried both multi-line `i18n-tasks-use` statements, but can't seem to get it to work.

Is there any way to create a multi-line `i18n-tasks-use` statement? Is there a better solution here?

Comment: Can you share an example of how the line looks?

Comment: @AndyWaite added an example in the question!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression in the `IgnoredPatterns` configuration option to tell RuboCop to ignore lines matching it. Example:

```
# .rubocop.yml

Metrics/LineLength:
  IgnoredPatterns:
    - !ruby/regexp '^\w*# i18n-tasks-use.*$'
```

You might need to adjust the regular expression to your use case.